# how to check handlebar-template completely rendered

Tags: callback

i have a handlebar-template in B.phtml file like this:

```
<div class="conversation-header" id="conversation-header" >
    <div class="avatar">
        <a href="{{profileUrl}}">
            {{> avatar showHardcore=false}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This template is going to append A.html file which have been add eventlistener 'load' then will do something.
But it can't check exactly when the handlebars-template completely rendered.

May i have a callback for B.phtml or sth like that and can i write this on A.phtml ?